# Merging two csv in Pandas and I get an empty column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I am using this code to merge two csv files that are formatted like this:

```
buyer         product
<address>     <code>
<address>     <code>
<address>     <code>
```

and

```
product          seller
<code>        <address>
<code>        <address>
<code>        <address>
```

```
import pandas as pd


buyers = pd.read_csv("buyers.csv")
sellers = pd.read_csv("sellers.csv")

merged = pd.merge(buyers, sellers, on="product", how="outer")
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```

and my output csv looks like this:

```
buyer         product        seller
<address>     <code>
<address>     <code>
<address>     <code>
```

The last column is completely blank and I can't seem to figure out why. Is there something wrong with my input or am I going about this completely wrong? I am trying to put the two data sets together such that they merge where the code is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I think there may be something going on with the underlying data, as the code seems to work as expected. Are you able to give us a sample?

Outside of that, I would double check that the product data type is the same across both dataframes.

```
buyers.dtypes
sellers.dtypes
```

---

```
dic1 = {'buyer':[13,23,53],'product':[1,2,3]}
dic2 = {'product':[1,2,3],'seller':['add1','add2','add3']}

buyer = pd.DataFrame(dic1)
seller = pd.DataFrame(dic2)

merged = pd.merge(buyer,seller,on='product',how='outer')
merged
```

[image: My Output]

Comment: so the only thing i can think of is the underlying data in the column i'm merging on has a few corrupted entries. A handful are repeated and some are blank. Do they all have to be 100% accurate for this to work or do i need to filter those out first? Thank you for your reply

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "corrupted." Blank values should be totally fine, will just insert new rows with the data available.

As I side note, I would absolutely recommend cleaning the data to be your first step after loading

Comment: oh by corrupted i just mean that when i pull the data some entries that should be there are not and so there are less rows on one than the other. If that wouldn't affect the output then i don't know what could be wrong.